How do I launch an Android activity in the same process that is launching it?
I have some activities that I want to launch. Sometimes I want to launch the activity from my main process (e.g. another activity), and sometimes I want to launch them from my service which is running in a different process. Note that none of these activities are exported.
I assumed that the <activity android:process="..."/> default behavior was to launch in the current process, but that's not true. The default behavior is to launch in the default process for the application.
I could create copies of all of my <activity> elements with a different class that specifies an android:process, but this is undesirable for reasons.
It looks like android:multiprocess="true" makes the default work the way I want it to, but I've seen vague, second-hand, dire warnings about using that, but original sources have been taken down, and in practice it seems to do exactly what I want.
Is there another, better way to accomplish this?
